# raspberry pi 3 multiple cameras with recording function

Tags: camera

I'm doing a surveillance system project of multiple cameras on a Raspberry Pi with a recording function. Is it possible to record video from two or more cameras at the same time from a single Raspberry Pi board?

I bought a [multiplexer](http://www.ivmech.com/magaza/en/development-modules-c-4/ivport-raspberry-pi-camera-module-multiplexer-p-90) from ivmech, but only one of the cameras can be switched on at a time.

Is there any solution for recording video simultaneously from either Raspberry Pi cameras or USB cameras? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: If the OP is still interested in a solution, I too have been working on Home Sec project with my Pi2. I ran across this link earlier today. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/18/multiple-cameras-with-the-raspberry-pi-and-opencv/

Comment: @Eddie hallo I'm trying to use the same board but I had no luck and found also a possible error on the board can u help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not realistically, no. The single camera limit on the Raspberry Pi isn't arbitrary; it's a hardware issue. As it is currently designed, the RPi is not capable of processing multiple video streams. That requires very specialized hardware, which usually takes the forms of multiple GPUs.

**Edit**: I thought I'd add a source

> No it is not possible on the Raspberry Pi
>
> Use two Pi's and the network maybe...
>
> Gordon (Raspberry Pi Engineer)

(note added by me)

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=50142

**Edit 2:**:

> Is there any solution for recording video simultaneously from either raspberry pi cameras or **USB cameras**?

(emphasis mine)

I missed the part about USB cameras. Yes, you can process multiple cameras through a USB interface. The [link in the comments](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/18/multiple-cameras-with-the-raspberry-pi-and-opencv/) is a good example of how to use openCV. I'd also recommend their own [website's documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

Comment: The 3 has a dual core GPU.  I'm a bit dubious about the general assertion here as well, although I agree it probably isn't very feasible on a Pi anyway.

Comment: @goldilocks: GPU cores are not the same thing as CPU cores...

Comment: Fair enough, but I still don't see why the *OS* would be limited in the manner you describe.  If it is handling multiple streams from USB devices, I don't see why it could not alternate processing through the GPU...except of course that *might* lead to a latency and buffering issue that grows without bounds.  So I guess having not tried this I'll take your word for it ;)

Comment: I do not require all of them streaming on one screen but at least one. I just want to record and save the videos on an external hard drive

Comment: @Eddie: that would involve the "processing" step that the RPi is incapable of doing.

Comment: would the RPi be able to work on 2 cameras only ? I have found this blog showing 2 cameras that work simultaneously http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/18/multiple-cameras-with-the-raspberry-pi-and-opencv/

Comment: @Eddie: That usings USB web cameras, not the camera port your board supports.

Comment: so can I use 1 RPi camera and one or more USB web cameras for my surveillance system ?

Comment: @Eddie: see the latest update. I'm not sure how well the CSI interface would play with USB. You might need to use all USB devices.

Comment: @Jacobm001: i have reconsidered my project and wanna build the surveillance system on N RPis with N cameras. I found this as an example for build the system. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/665518/Raspberry-Pi-as-low-cost-HD-surveillance-camera Could you please explain how can i actually connect two RPis by network which videos can be both streamed and saved at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with https://www.kerberos.io/. However more than one camera is not supported by default, and you have to make some changes in the config file.

Also, it doesn't take video, but rather a series of pictures when motion is detected.

You can read more about it here: https://doc.kerberos.io/2.0/installation/Multi-camera/Raspbian

I have used Keberos.io with one camera and it works great for what I need it for.